# Explode the word from sentence regardless of any special characters using PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have this function to explode the word from sentence:

```
function explode_words($input_string='')
    {
        $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $input_string); //Here REGEX
        return $keywords; // as array
    }
```

I give an example here:

```
$input_string = 'Pokok < getah < > sumber asli! yang bernilai . Banyak produk guna getah ?';
```

The exploded words will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Pokok
    [1] => <
    [2] => getah
    [3] => <
    [4] => >
    [5] => sumber
    [6] => asli!
    [7] => yang
    [8] => bernilai
    [9] => .
    [10] => Banyak
    [11] => produk
    [12] => guna
    [13] => getah
    [14] => ?
)
```

How to exclude all the special characters like `~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?'` ?

The word `asli!` should return only `asli` only.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks and have nice Monday!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
function explode_words($input_string='')
{
    $keywords = array_filter(explode(' ', preg_replace('/[^ a-z]/i','',$input_string)));
    return $keywords;
}
```

- Remove special characters
- Explode words by whitespace
- Filter out empty parts of array

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Pokok
    [2] => getah
    [5] => sumber
    [6] => asli
    [7] => yang
    [8] => bernilai
    [10] => Banyak
    [11] => produk
    [12] => guna
    [13] => getah
)
```

Comment: The result returned `[0] => PokokgetahsumberasliyangbernilaiBanyakprodukgunagetah`

Comment: @Imran: It's a typo, change `preg_replace` to `preg_split`

Comment: But it return error => `preg_split() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given`

Comment: @Imran - sorry, i missed a space in the regex.  see updated answer.  tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `"/[^\p{L}]+/"` to split the string.

```
function explode_words($input_string = "")        {
    return preg_split("/[^\p{L}]+/u", $input_string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

`\p{L}` is a Unicode category that includes lowercase, uppercase, etc. alphabetic characters (you can look at it as an expanded version of `[a-zA-Z]` that includes characters from most alphabets in the world).

The `[^...]` part means "anything **not** in this group".

Comment: I liked this method.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work with combining characters. Other thing since you use a unicode character class to deal with unicode strings, you should use the u modifier.

Comment: Now, If I set the condition only certain special characters like `/` or `%` or `.` are allowed else excluded. How to do this?

Comment: @Imran: `preg_split` is problematic for this kind of case. It's easier to build a pattern for allowed characters and to use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? @CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to specify what you need to retain like so,

```
preg_split("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", $input_string, NULL,  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

In this example, a-z and A-Z are allow ranges. You could change it as needed.